# Too many values to unpack in ternary operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-operator

Why in the second line of below code snippet of ternary operator there are 3 values to unpack, I am expecting it to be 2:

```
x,y=5,10
x,y=100,20 if x<5 else 30,40
print(x,y)
```

Output: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
x,y=5,10
x,y,z=100,20 if x<5 else 30,40
print(x,y,z)
```

Output: 100 30 40

Comment: Put parentheses `()` around the tuples: `x, y = (100, 20) if x < 5 else (30, 40)`. Also, spacing improves readability significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are writing is the following:

```py
x, y = (100), (20 if x < 5 else 30), (40)
```

You are missing some parenthesis. Python can't determine automatically what is a tuple and what isn't. What you actually want to do is this:

```py
x, y = (100, 20) if x < 5 else (30, 40)
```